# SQL for last x events of type

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to find which members have had the best attendance over the last x events where event type matters

Example structure here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bde53/1

`attended_id` is the members id, Given many events with many event types i would like something like this if possible

```
 attended_id | last 6 event 1 | last 12 event 2 |  2013 event 3 |
       1             6               10                6
       2             5                9                12
       3             2                8                7
```

`2013 event 3` means all event id's 3 which occured in 2013
is this possible or is it best to export to excel to get this information ?

Also open to new structures if it makes this query easier. The numbers should be easily changeable eg getting the last 8 event 1's instead of the last 6

I have SQL for each but cant combine them

Events in the last year by member id

```sql
SELECT attended_id, year(x.date), count(event_id)  FROM events e INNER JOIN events_types x USING (event_id)
INNER JOIN events_type t USING (event_type)
WHERE t.event_type = 1
group by attended_id, year(x.`date`);
```

last x events of type

```sql
SELECT attended_id, count(event_id) FROM events e INNER JOIN events_types x USING (event_id)
INNER JOIN events_type t USING (event_type)
WHERE t.event_type = 1 and
e.event_id >= (             
select event_id from events_types where event_type = 1 order by event_id desc
limit 1,1              
)
group by attended_id
```

I just cant combine these to show both on the same query

Comment: **'Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results'** ---- You've submitted the expected results but you haven't submitted your attempt and the reason for failure.

Comment: Now that's not really a representative data set, is it?

Comment: Updated the SQL fiddle with more data and the querys which i can use currently @PaparazzoKid

Comment: @Sly Raskal: please don't remove the SQL tag from questions related to SQL. The database-specific tag does not mean the SQL should not be present. Language and platform are two different things.

Comment: Im not sure why all the negative votes ? What else should i add ?

Comment: @Mat, have you read the description for the 'sql' tag? This question is pertinent to MySQL as evident by the use of MySQL 5.5.32 in the SQLFiddle that the poster submitted.  An excerpt of the description of the 'sql' tag specifically states *'This tag refers to the standard language, not for questions about a specific DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server). So if you think your question relates to a specific DBMS, use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ANSI SQL as much as possible.'* MySQL Tag supercedes SQL Tag, plain/simple.

Comment: @Mat If the mysql tag is removed, then I see your point, but based on the 'sql' tag description, you shouldn't have both the 'sql' tag and a database specific tag on a single post.

Comment: @SlyRaskal: I don't believe the OP is looking for or actively battling with MySQL specific SQL extensions. If this question was about stored procedures in MySQL, then the SQL tag would be invalid. It's not, it's about plain SQL, and the MySQL tag gives context.

Comment: @sly raskal. Yes I'm using mysql but any sql answer will be fine. I'm not only interested in mysql specific sql

Comment: @Mat, I understand that, and if that is the case, then the 'MySQL' tag should be removed.

Comment: @SlyRaskal: certainly not. It gives context as I said. And there might be MySQL-specific tricks that solve the OP's problem that would be appropriate in an answer here. Or plain ANSI SQL might be enough.

Comment: @user1281385: Thanks for the clarification, I would suggest removing the mysql tag then.

Comment: @Mat, I see your point, then in that case, perhaps the 'sql' tags decription is inaccurate, and shouldn't say the word 'instead' which implies one or the other.  Trust me I do see your point, but the tag's description can be ambiguous because of it's wording.

Comment: Please re-read your question again and then re-write it in English. Clearly and comprehensibly describe your tables and what you are trying to do. Sentences like "'2013 event 3' means all event id's 3" is certainly not in English.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve... Could you be more specific and shrtly describe what **Last 6 event 1** and **Last 12 event 2** means. By The Way: up-voted!

Comment: @MaciejLos there's no reason to upvote this sh*tty question, at least not until it gets fixed!

Comment: @Tomas, there is one reason only: to encourage OP to improve His/Her question ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos `last 6 event 1` means the most recent 6 event that are event type 1. If Event 1 was daily, it would mean how many events in the last 6 days for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query can be achieved by:

- using [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) to calculate the age rank of each event type in one pass
- joining the attendance records to the ranked results, grouping on `attended_id`

Here's the query:

```
select
  a.attended_id,
  sum(event_type = 1 and rank <= 6) `last 6 event 1`,
  sum(event_type = 2 and rank <= 12) `last 12 event 2`,
  sum(event_type = 3 and year(date) = 2013) `2013 event 3`
from events a
left join (
  select event_id, event_type, date,
    (@row := if(@prev is null or @row is null or @prev != event_type, 1, @row + 1)) rank,
    (@prev := event_type) prev
  from (select event_id, event_type, date
    from events_types
    order by event_type, date desc) e) r on r.event_id = a.event_id
group by 1
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fedc1/34)

As you can see, it would be a simple matter to change the variables to have different event types and "last n" values, or even to add more columns for different breakdowns.

Notes:

- the inner-most query orders the rows by event then date oldest-to-newest. This is required for the rank logic to work properly
- the tests for the variables being `null` are only needed for the first row, but are used to avoid having to define the variables in a separate statement, making the query a single stand-alone query, which is often required because most database libraries don't support multiple queries executed in a single call
- lengthy `case` statements are avoided by *summing* a condition; in mysql booleans are 1 for true and 0 for false, so summing a condition *counts* how many times it was true

A final note, your table names are a bit confusing. They could be changed to make it more clear what their meaning is. I suggest these changes:

- `events` --> `attendances`
- `events_types` --> `events`
- `events_type` --> `event_types`

Comment: @user1281385 does this query do what you wanted?

Comment: yes this works, But uses the same technique as the other answer, Though this code is "better" `<= 6` rather than `between 1 and 6` etc. Ive awarded to the other answer for posting the technique first. Thanks !

Comment: This query does NOT use the same technique at all! It is totally different and much much more efficient. This query only makes one pass for all results - the other query makes one pass for every result. His second query is copied from mine - it only appeared after I posted my answer. I can't believe you awarded the bounty to the other answer...

Comment: I will move the accepted answer to yours, I didnt check the edit history sorry. I seen his answer was posted first

Comment: to be honest, it's not the tick, it's the bounty - it would have given me a hat :(

Answer (score 3):

please try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fedc1/2/0)

```
SELECT T1.attended_id,
       T2.`last 6 event 1`,
       T3.`last 12 event 2`,
       T4.`2013 event 3`
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT attended_id
     FROM events)T1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT e.attended_id,COUNT(*) as `last 6 event 1`
     FROM events e
     INNER JOIN (SELECT event_id,event_type,date
                 FROM events_types
                 WHERE event_type = 1
                 ORDER BY date DESC
                 LIMIT 6
                ) et
     USING (event_id)
     GROUP BY e.attended_id
     )T2
ON (T1.attended_id = T2.attended_id)
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT e.attended_id,COUNT(*) as `last 12 event 2`
     FROM events e
     INNER JOIN (SELECT event_id,event_type,date
                 FROM events_types
                 WHERE event_type = 2
                 ORDER BY date DESC
                 LIMIT 12
                ) et
     USING (event_id)
     GROUP BY e.attended_id
     )T3
ON (T1.attended_id = T3.attended_id)
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT e.attended_id,COUNT(*) as `2013 event 3`
     FROM events e
     INNER JOIN (SELECT event_id,event_type,date
                 FROM events_types
                 WHERE event_type = 3
                 AND year(date) = 2013
                 ) et
     USING (event_id)
     GROUP BY e.attended_id
     )T4
ON (T1.attended_id = T4.attended_id)
```

your sqlFiddle doesn't have enough data so I added some random `events` and some `event_types` and I noticed that you don't need to join with `event_type` since you're not grabbing any information from `event_type` but only wanted a count.

If you wanted last 8 event 1, just change the `LIMIT 6` to `LIMIT 8` inside `et` of `T2`

OR you can try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fedc1/23/0) with code below

```
SELECT e.attended_id,
       SUM(IF(event_type = 1 AND typeRank BETWEEN 1 AND 6,1,0)) as `last 6 event 1`,
       SUM(IF(event_type = 2 AND typeRank BETWEEN 1 AND 12,1,0)) as `last 12 event 2`,
       SUM(IF(event_type = 3 AND YEAR(date) = 2013,1,0)) as `2013 event 3`
FROM events e
INNER JOIN (SELECT event_id,event_type,date,
                   IF (@prevType != event_type,@typeRank:=1,@typeRank:=@typeRank+1) as typeRank,
                   @prevType := event_type
            FROM events_types,(SELECT @prevType:=0,@typeRank:=0)R
            ORDER BY event_type,date DESC
            ) et
USING (event_id)
GROUP BY e.attended_id
```

if you wanted last 8 event 1 just change the `BETWEEN 1 AND 6` to `BETWEEN 1 AND 8`

Comment: This is the output i want, But look at the explain, So many temporary and file sort's any way to avoid that ?

Comment: try the query on bottom of my answer you might like that one better since it's more compacted!

Comment: Thats much better ! Thanks alot :)